# Storing data per thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

### Exposition

I have some processing I need to do over a big buffer of data.
I can represent my calculations in the form `result[i] = F(SomeSubsetOf(input))` so it's really easy to do all these calculations in parallel. the problem is I'm using a little temp buffer for some of the manipulations, and i don't want to allocate one for each calculation, i want to allocate them only on a per thread basis.

### The actual question

How do i define a variable to be unique only per thread. for example:

```
int Calculate(byte[] buffer, int resultIndex)
{
    byte temp = new byte[8];

    CopyStuff(buffer, resultIndex -4 , temp, 8) // please dont be pendatic about this line

    DoSomeStuff(temp)l

    return GetAverage(temp);
}
```

now I intend to run this function using `Parallel.For` and `temp` has to be unique only for every executing thread, and obviously can be recycled for every calculation the same thread executes.
What would be the simplest and most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the third parameter here:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299.aspx

It initializes  local data for every task executing the iterations.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare `temp` as a property, wrapped in `ThreadLocal`, and then access it's value by the `Value` property.

See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx).